# Why use a Service over an IntentService?

Tags: android, android-service, android-syncadapter, android-background

Why does the `SyncService` example provided by Google below use a `Service` instead of an `IntentService`? It is my understanding that `IntentServices` run in the background, while a regular `Service` will run in the main thread. For something with no UI that just updates data, why would you want it run in the main thread? Doesn't that risk frame-drops?

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#CreateSyncAdapterService

Is it possible to have a standalone `IntentService`? or does it need to be based off something running on the main thread? This is the only reason I can see why we would use a regular `Service` above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is my understanding that IntentServices run in the background, while a regular Service will run in the main thread.

Objects do not run on threads. Methods do.

`IntentService` inherits from `Service`. The main lifecycle methods on `Service`, notably `onStartCommand()` are called on the main application thread. `IntentService` happens to provide a background thread, which it uses to call your `onHandleIntent()` method, triggered by a call to `onStartCommand()`.

> For something with no UI that just updates data, why would you want it run in the main thread?

You don't.

> Why does the SyncService example provided by Google below use a Service instead of an IntentService?

Because an `IntentService` is inappropriate here. Quoting the documentation that you linked to:

> To do this, you need to create a bound Service that passes a special Android binder object from the sync adapter component to the framework. With this binder object, the framework can invoke the onPerformSync() method and pass data to it.

`IntentService` and the binding pattern do not work well together.

From a threading standpoint, [`onPerformSync()` is called on a background thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html), supplied by Android. Hence, even if `IntentService` were not ruled out based upon binding, you do not need *another* background thread, since `onPerformSync()` is already called on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you. I think my issue is that I am creating a LocationListener in the onCreate() method of my service (to get the user's current location), so when the SyncAdapter's onPerformSync() is called - it's using an updated location.

Do you have a better idea as to where I should create my LocationListener (it uses the network provider, and only gets the user's current location once).

Comment: @user891242: IMHO, getting the user's location has nothing to do with synchronizing with a server (the point of `SyncAdapter`).

Comment: Well, in my weather app, I have a CheckboxPreference that lets the user use his current location for weather data. When i check the box, I want the SyncAdapter is sync immediately using the new location. Based on your advice, I will asynchronously get the new location using an IntentService, then call the SyncAdapter service when the new location is retrieved.